# How to do double include in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I got problem with the following pieces of code:

```
public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }
    public Subject CourseSubject { get; set; }
    public List<Student> CourseAttendeeStudents { get; set; }
    public Teacher CourseTeacher { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        CourseNotes = new List<CourseNote>();
        CourseAttendeeStudents = new List<Student>();
        CourseSubject = new Subject();
        CourseId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

I need to gather all information about all courses so I do the following:

```
var coursed = db.Courses.Include(p=>p.CourseAttendeeStudents).Include(p=>p.CourseTeacher);
```

However, the Students and the Teacher contains another lists inside themselves. 
How can I do something like:

```
var coursed = db.Courses.Include(p=>p.CourseAttendeeStudents.Include...).Include(p=>p.CourseTeacher.Include...);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this article about entity loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

There's a section called Eagerly loading multiple levels.

The example they give:

```
// Load all blogs, all related posts, and all related comments 
var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                   .Include(b => b.Posts.Select(p => p.Comments)) 
                   .ToList();
```

Maybe something like:

```
var coursed = db.Courses
                .Include(p => p.CourseAttendeeStudents.Select(s => s.OtherListInsideAttendeeStudent))
                .Include(p => p.CourseAttendeeStudents.StudentProperty.Select(s =>s.OtherListInsideStudentProperty))
                .Include(p => p.CourseTeacher.Select(s => s.OtherListInsideTeacher));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of Entity Framework you are running, but at least in Core, there's a "ThenInclude" function you could use.

```
var coursed = db.Courses
   .Include(p=>p.CourseAttendeeStudents)
        .ThenInclude(courseAttendeeStudents => courseAttendeeStudents.Property)
   .Include(p=>p.CourseTeacher)
        .ThenInclude(courseTeacher => courseTeacher.Property);
```

As shown, it builds onto the Include() you already did. You can continue to add ThenInclude on.